# Finding the missing values from a given range

Tags: c, arrays, linear-algebra, algebra

How can I calculate all the missing values between a particular range of numbers
where a missing number is equal to ***average*** of ***next*** and ***previous*** values of given input range

**Example**

Number of missing values = 2

Array :  **[5, ?, ?, 20]**

Result: **5,10,15,20**

Simply doing (5+25)/4+1 i.e. missing values+1 gives you 5 which we add to our first value gives 5 10 15 20 but doesn't work with other examples like

**[6,?,?,?,20]** (3 missing values)

Comment: Can you properly explain the condition?```(i.e. where a missing number is equal to average of next and previous values of given input range)```

Comment: As in my example the first missing value i.e. 10 is the average of 5 and 15 and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like calculate the difference between the first and the last number you know, 20-5=15 on the example, and now you just divivide it to the number of "steps" you want to get the last one (number of missing number + 1), 15/3 = 5 on the example, and now you just add that quantity to each element to get the next one.

Something like this:

[5, (5+5), ((5+5)+5), 20]

You can verify it works for the second example too with 3 missing values.

Comment: In the second example (20-6)/4 = 3 and series will be 6,9,12,15,20. But the average of the last two is 16, not 15.

Comment: @P__J__ it would be a nicer problem with integers, such as 6,9,12,16,20.

Answer (score 3):

Your condition that each number is equal to the average of the next and previous numbers, which you could write as:

*x*<sub>*i*</sub> = (*x*<sub>*i*+1</sub> + *x*<sub>*i*-1</sub>) / 2

can easily be rearranged to:

*x*<sub>*i*</sub> - *x*<sub>*i*-1</sub> = *x*<sub>*i*+1</sub> - *x*<sub>*i*</sub>

In other words, the differences between adjacent numbers are all the same.

So this is just a simple linear interpolation. As you've tagged this with C, here's a simple C function to evaluate your example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calc_values(float start, float end, int n) {
  int i;
  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    printf("%f\n",
       start + (end - start) * i / (n + 1));
}

int main()
{
   calc_values(6, 20, 3);
   return 0;
}
```

which gives:

```
9.500000
13.000000
16.500000
```